# jquery widget _trigger and bind

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

I am trying to make my jquery widgets loosely coupled, but the use of _trigger and bind is not working as expected.

Here is my widget (using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404085 as a ref):

```
(function ($, undefined) {
  $.widget('qs.tagger', {
    _create: function () {
      var that = this,
        name = this.name;

      that.element.bind('mouseenter', function (event) {
        that._trigger('activated', event, {name: 'hello'});
        console.log('mouseenter');
      });
    },
    destroy: function () {
      this._destroy();
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

calling it looks like this

```
$('#results').tagger();
```

and this is the instantiation and bind:

```
  $('#results').tagger();

  $('#search-form').bind('taggeractivated', function (event, data) {
    console.log('world');
  });
```

when I check the console.log I see the mouse enter event being fired, but I never see the bind ing event being called.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way the widget factory _trigger method works. If you want to use the _trigger you have to do it like this:

```
$('#results').tagger({
     activated: function (event, data) {

          console.log('hello activated world');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#results').tagger();
$('#search-form').on('activated', function (event, data) {console.log('world');});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your HTML structure I'm taking a stab in the dark and saying the `$('#results')` element is not a descendant of the `$('#search-form')` element. Events thrown by the plugin can only be caught by the object on which the plugin was instantiated or ancestors. If you want more help, please provide the HTML, or even better, provide HTML and JavaScript via [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Any way that I can catch the event outside of the plugin itself? And you are right, #results is not a descendant of #search-form